# Solve $\frac{d^2y}{d x^2}+2 \frac{d y}{d x} \tan x+2 y \tan ^2 x=4 \cos ^2 x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: solve the following differential equation.

$\frac{d^2y}{d x^2}+2 \frac{d y}{d x} \tan x+2 y \tan ^2 x=4 \cos ^2 x
\\
,y(0)=0 , dy/dx|_ {x=0} =0 
$

Hint:
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}+p(x) \frac{d y}{d x}+q(x) y=f(x) \quad \quad (1) \\
v(x)=\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} \int p(x) d x\right), y(x)=u(x) v(x) \quad \quad (2) \\
\frac{d^2 u}{d x^2}+P(x) u=R(x) \quad \quad (3)
\end{array}
Let's think about equation (1).
If you set v(x) like equation (2), you can express equation(1) in the form of equation(3).

Can someone please help me with solving this problem? I have no idea. Aslo is there a name of the method used in the hint?

Comment: Sorry, I'm now sure what this problem is about. Which tag should I use then?

Comment: What you have is a non-linear ODE, whereas your hints are all normally used for linear ODEs. So are you sure you have the right ODE? Also, you should remove the PDE and stochastic DE tags, your problem is just a regular ODE problem.

Comment: Just the ODE tag. This is not a stochastic equation either.

Comment: Thanks I edited the tag. And also edited the equation.
The correct equation is below:
22+2tan+2tan2=4cos2. And I miss-typed it as 22+2ytan+2tan2=4cos2.

Comment: Why don't you follow the hint i.e., substitute $y= u\cos x$ and find $P(x)$ and $R(x)$ on your own? You should not expect others to solve the entire problem for you. Regarding (3), you can use [the method of variation of parameters](https://qr.ae/py4lc8) to solve it.

Comment: you are right. Thanks for the link. I will try and ask again

Answer (score 1):

We try the transformation $y(x)=\cos(t)\cdot u(t)$ and $x=t$.
That results in ODE:
$$u''(t)-u\! \left(t\right)+4 \cos(t)=0,\quad u(0)=0, u'(0)=0$$

The solution is easy to obtain:
$$u(t)=2\cosh(t)-2 \cos\! \left(t\right)$$
$$\implies y(x)=\cos(x)\cdot u(x)=2 \cos\! \left(x\right)\cdot \left(\cosh\! \left(x\right)-\cos\! \left(x\right)\right)$$

Comment: How is this substitution motivated?

Comment: Trial and error.